# Is there a pure Java library to import OVA/VMDK as VM in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, java

I know the command line tool given by Amazon and its use from Java. But then, is there a pure Java open source SDK available to import a VMDK as a VM in Amazon AWS ?